# how to make a 2nd button to click only when first button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have the two input type:

```
// First Submit Button:
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>

// Second Button:   
<input type="button" value="Go for payment" id="payment" />
```

i want button with the `id="payment"` to be function/click only when the `Submit` is clicked  when the data is saved only .
**Please provide any suggestion. I am new to jquery and javascript**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.prop()` like this:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $('#payment').prop('disabled',false);    
});
```

Make sure that you're putting `disabled` attribute for `#payment` button.

```
<input type="button" value="Go for payment" id="payment" disabled />
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4CS3H/)**

Comment: Upvoting this because people have been abusing `.attr()` too much — `.prop()` should be used when dealing with boolean attributes. And kudos for using `.prop('disabled', false)` instead of `.removeProp('disabled')`. That is the right way! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to enable the 2nd button after the 1st button has been clicked:

Please see below for a coded example:

```
//On document load
$(function(){
      //Set button disabled
      $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");

      //Append a change event listener to you inputs
      $('input').change(function(){
            //Validate your form here, example:
            var validated = true;
            if($('#nome').val().length === 0) validated = false;

            //If form is validated enable form
            if(validated) $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");                             
      });

      //Trigger change function once to check if the form is validated on page load
      $('input:first').trigger('change');
})
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I would avoid using `.attr()` to set boolean attributes. Use `.prop()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
.visable {
   visibility: hidden;
}
<input id="payment" class="visable"/>

$("input[type='submit']").on('click',function(){
$("#payment").css("visibility", "visible");

});
```

Just by using css.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
<input type="button" value="Go for payment" id="payment" />
```

In script:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $('#payment').click();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I this this code will solve your problem:

```
<body>
<form>
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
<input type="button" value="Go for payment" id="payment"/>
</form>
</body>

<script>
$("form").submit(function( event ) {
  $( "#payment" ).trigger( "click" );
});

$( "#payment" ).click(function() {
  alert("Hello");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WY9d2/)

```
$("#submit").click(function(){    

$("#payment").removeAttr('disabled');
});
```